# Building dependent dropdown with Ajax and Jquery: having trouble getting 2 php GET variables to show up on get_state.php - ajax is sending too

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql-server, ajax

I have `index.php?WORKORDER_BASE_ID=w21592` -> This is getting the work order number that I entered, that searches the MSSQL DATABASE. I call `$_GET['WORKORDER_BASE_ID'];` to be used to run other queries to get database results.

I need a dependent drop down. The first drop down runs the query and returns the result and it uses ajax to go to `get_state.php`. There it's showing up undefined varialbe/index when I try to CALL `$_GET['WORKORDER_BASE_ID'];` to run the 2nd query and output it in the second dropdown. How can I get around this?

```html
<?php
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
$query ="SELECT DISTINCT R.PART_ID AS PartId, R.PART_ID  +  '  (' +P.DESCRIPTION + ')'  AS PartFull
  FROM REQUIREMENT AS R INNER JOIN PART AS P 
  ON R.PART_ID = P.ID
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT PART_ID FROM TRACE_PROFILE TP WHERE R.PART_ID=TP.PART_ID) 
  AND  (R.WORKORDER_BASE_ID = '".$_GET["WORKORDER_BASE_ID"]."')";
$results = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
?>
<html>
<head>
<TITLE>jQuery Dependent DropDown List - Countries and States</TITLE>
<head>
<style>
body{width:610px;}
.frmDronpDown {border: 1px solid #F0F0F0;background-color:#C8EEFD;margin: 2px 0px;padding:40px;}
.demoInputBox {padding: 10px;border: #F0F0F0 1px solid;border-radius: 4px;background-color: #FFF;width: 50%;}
.row{padding-bottom:15px;}
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function getState(val) {
 $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "index.php",
 data:'PartFull='+val,
 success: function(data){
  $("#state-list").html(data);
 }
 });
}

function selectCountry(val) {
$("#search-box").val(val);
$("#suggesstion-box").hide();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<? 
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$dateunix = new DateTime();
$dateunix = $dateunix->getTimestamp();
?>
<input type="textarea" name="WORKORDER_BASE_ID" rows="3" cols="5" id="WORKORDER_BASE_ID" value="<?= $_GET["WORKORDER_BASE_ID"];?>" data-theme="f" class="ui-input-text ui-body-f ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"   required>
   <input method="get" id="button"   type="submit">
<h5>WORK ORDER ID:</h5><labelh5><center><? echo $_GET["WORKORDER_BASE_ID"];?></center></labelh5> 
<div class="frmDronpDown">
<div class="row">
<label>Partid:</label><br/>
<select name="PartFull" id="partfull-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getState(this.value);">
<option value="">Select Part Id:</option>
<?php
foreach($results as $country) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $country["PartId"]; ?>"><?php echo $country["PartFull"]; ?> </option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label>op seq no:</label><br/>
<select name="state" id="state-list" class="demoInputBox">
<option value="">Select Operation Seq. NO</option>
</select>

</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

get_state.php

```html
  
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

    <title>GET STATE </title>
  
  
  


<!-- jQuery  -->  
    <link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery  -->  
    
    
    </head>
    
    
    <body>
  <input name="WORKORDER_BASE_ID" type="hidden" value="<?= $_GET["WORKORDER_BASE_ID"];?>" />

<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$dateunix = new DateTime();
$dateunix = $dateunix->getTimestamp();

require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
if($_GET["PartFull"] != "") { 

 
  echo $wobi;
  echo $_GET['PartFull'];
 
  echo $_GET['WORKORDER_BASE_ID'];
 
 $query ="SELECT DISTINCT R.OPERATION_SEQ_NO AS OSN, '(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), R.OPERATION_SEQ_NO) + ')  ' + O.RESOURCE_ID AS Expr1
FROM OPERATION 
AS O 
INNER JOIN REQUIREMENT AS R 
ON R.OPERATION_SEQ_NO = O.SEQUENCE_NO AND O.WORKORDER_BASE_ID = R.WORKORDER_BASE_ID
 
WHERE (R.WORKORDER_BASE_ID =  '".$_GET['WORKORDER_BASE_ID']."') AND (R.PART_ID = '" . $_GET["PartFull"] . "')";
 
 
 
 
 $results = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
?>
 <option value="">Select Operation Seq. NO 2</option>
<?php
 foreach($results as $state) {
?>
 <option value="<?php echo $state["OSN"]; ?>"><?php echo $state["Expr1"]; ?></option>
<?php
 }
}


?>
</body>
</html>
```